# How to get the correction commands while doing free dictation with sapi 5.3?

Tags: speech-recognition, sapi

I have an sample application that do basic dictation with sapi 5.3.
It works well to input text with punctuation...
What would I need to do to enable the correction functionality as in the tutorial (correct word, select ...)?
Is there a specific grammar to load (which and how), some specific events to implement?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you just want the **grammar**, you can use a ruleref to get the dictation grammar:

`<ruleref uri="sharing:Microsoft.SpeechUX.BuiltIn.LaunchCommands"/>`

Note that you'll still be responsible for parsing the rule and performing the actions.

Comment: Oops.  That should be
<ruleref uri="sharing:Microsoft.SpeechUX.BuiltIn.DictationCommands"/>

LaunchCommands gets you the list of applications you can launch.  D'Oh!